# Check user ids (Firebase and Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm new to Firebase and I apologise in advance if this question is a little 'beginner' or confusing.

I'm playing around with a project learning to use firebase and I have two user types "doctor" and "patient". I've been able to set up a signup and login system which is working perfect. Currently if you sign up as doctor you segue to doctor page and if you sign up as patient you segue to patient page. I've also set up so that once you launch the app if you are already logged in you skip the login/signup page and segue straight to the homepage.

My issue is that it doesn't matter if you are logged in as doctor or patient it automatically segues to the patient homepage on launch. I'm trying to do a check where if the current user id is a user id under the "Patient" node in the database then to segue to the patient homepage otherwise if the current user id is under the "Doctor" node in the database then to segue to the doctor homepage else print the local error to console. This is where i'm currently stuck at and any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

This is my current code that automatically segues you to homepage if you are logged in at launch of app and it is on the initial view controller :

```
        FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in

        if user != nil{

            print("User is signed in.")

            //send the user to the PatientHomeViewController

            let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main",bundle:nil)

            let PatientHomeViewController: UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PatientHomeViewController")

            //send the user to the patient homepage
            self.present(PatientHomeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    })
```

Thanks heaps in advance.

Comment: Not enough code here to help. Where is the controller logic that decides which view you segue into? Where are you loading the user roles to determine if they are patient or doctor? It'll help to include all the relevant code, sample data, debug logging, and version info so we can fully understand the problem. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to find a way to fix my issue. I know it's not the best fix but after a lot of testing it is working good with no issues. If anyone else has a similar issue the code I've used to fix my issue and to be able to check two types of users is:

```
        let rootRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in

        if(user != nil){

            rootRef.child("Patients").child((user?.uid)!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in

                if(snapshot.exists()) {

                    print("Patient is signed in.")

                    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main",bundle:nil)

                    let patientHomeViewController: UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PatientHomeViewController")

                    self.present(patientHomeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                } else {

                    print("Doctor is signed in.")

                    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main",bundle:nil)

                    let doctorHomeViewController: UIViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DoctorHomeViewController")

                    self.present(doctorHomeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                }
            })

        }

    })
```

If anyone has a better way to write this code please feel free to add it as a comment.

Thanks.